# Using generator expression with fuzzywuzzy to get Top 2 matches

Tags: python, generator, fuzzywuzzy

I'm trying to incorporate the use of generators with fuzzywuzzy's extract method to speed up my code but am struggling to store the top two matches along with their scores. I was able to do this before when I was storing "results" as a List object and am not sure if it's possible/appropriate to try the same operations with a generator object.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

lookup_list = ['Pepsi Co','Steel United','ADIGAS','Consulting Group LLC','Company ABCDY','Blueberry Corp','FoodIndustries','PETCEO', 'OxChem']
vals = ['Pepsi', 'Steel Untd', 'ADIDAS','Consulting Group', 'Company ABC','Bluuberrie Cor']

results = (process.extract(val, lookup_list, scorer=fuzz.WRatio, limit=2) for val in vals)

best_match = None
best_score = 0

best_match_2 = None
best_score_2 = 0

for result in results: 
    best_score, best_match = (result[0][1], result[0][0]) if result[0][1] > best_score else (best_score, best_match)
    best_score2, best_match2 = .....
```

Desired output:

```
best_score
95
best_match
'Consulting Group LLC'

best_score2
92
best_match
'Company ABCDY'
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking for? What exactly do you want `best_score2` etc to be? Is it supposed to be the best of the second matches, or is it the second best overall? If the latter, you should probably flatten your generator and use `heapq.nlargest`.

Comment: if i flatten the generator then they're no performances gains vs using a list

Comment: I think you can flatten the generator just by adding an extra loop to your generator expression. I'm not 100% sure I understand your data structure, but I think you'd want `(result for val in vals for result in process.extract(val, lookup_list, scorer=fuzz.WRatio, limit=2))`.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure I understand what speedup you're hoping for. Do you only want to process the second result if the first one is the current best?

Comment: i only want the two highest match scores, if i can avoid having to iterate over every element then that would be great and would save time. I'd only want to process the second result if the score is less than the first result or the same score but a different word

Answer (score 0):

in hindsight this was a pretty silly question, the confusion on my part was stemming from my inexperience with generators. Thank you @Blckknght for your suggestion, using heapq.nlargest pretty much solved everything.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

lookup_list = ['Pepsi Co','Steel United','ADIGAS','Consulting Group LLC','Company ABCDY','Blueberry Corp','FoodIndustries','PETCEO', 'OxChem']
vals = ['Pepsi', 'Steel Untd', 'ADIDAS','Consulting Group', 'Company ABC','Bluuberrie Cor']

results = (result for val in vals for result in process.extract(val, isv_lookup_list, scorer=fuzz.WRatio, limit=2))
top_two = heapq.nlargest(2, results, key=lambda x: x[1])

best_match_1, best_score_1 = top_two[0][0], top_two[0][1]
best_match_2, best_score_2 = top_two[1][0], top_two[1][1]
```

Output:

```
best_score
95
best_match
'Consulting Group LLC'

best_score2
92
best_match
'Company ABCDY'
```